# Task from cancellation token?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

Given a cancellation token, I'd like to create an awaitable task out of it, which is never complete but can be cancelled. I need it for a pattern like this, which IMO should be quite common:

```
async Task DoStuff(Task t, CancellationToken ct)
{
   // t was made from TaskCompletionSource, 
   // both t and ct are beyond my control

   Task t2 = TaskFromCancellationToken(ct);
   await Task.WhenAny(t, t2);

   // do stuff
}
```

The best idea I've got so far is this:

```
Task TaskFromCancelationToken(CancellationToken ct)
{
    return Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, ct);
}
```

Is there a better way to make this logic happen?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's not *extremely* common, but it's common enough to be part of my [AsyncEx](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) library. I use [something like](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20(NET45%2C%20Win8%2C%20WP8%2C%20WPA81)/CancellationTokenExtensions.cs) this:

```
public static Task AsTask(this CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    cancellationToken.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(),
        useSynchronizationContext: false);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

**Update:** These days, I recommend using something like [`CancellationTokenTaskSource`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/8a73d0467d40ca41f9f9cf827c7a35702243abb8/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/CancellationTokenTaskSource.cs), which properly handles all lifetimes with no possibility of resource leaks.

Comment: But [`cancellationToken.Register`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635(v=vs.110).aspx) returns [`CancellationTokenRegistration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokenregistration(v=vs.110).aspx), which you never dispose of (it implements `IDisposable`). Isn't that a problem?

Comment: @Paya: Yes. The current version of AsyncEx introduces a [`ToCancellationTokenTaskSource` method](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/Source/Nito.AsyncEx%20(NET45%2C%20Win8%2C%20WP8%2C%20WPA81)/CancellationTokenExtensions.cs#L28) which is recommended instead of `AsTask`. The [next version removes `AsTask` completely](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Tasks/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/CancellationTokenTaskSource.cs).

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer that over the suggested `Task.Delay`? That one seems like a very elegant solution and does not come with the `IDisposable` "annoyance".

Comment: @Paya: You still have the same resource leak; it's just not as noticeable.

Comment: Right. I guess there is no escaping `IDisposable` then. For the OP, maybe [UntilCompletionOrCancellation wrapper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173(v=vs.110).aspx#code-snippet-25) might be suitable alternative, if there is no need to keep the cancellation token task around.

Comment: @Paya: That's the same approach that I take in the new version of AsyncEx, with [`WaitAsync` and `WhenAnyAsync` extension methods](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Tasks/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskExtensions.cs).

Comment: @Paya in order not to leak the registration, all you have to do is dispose the `CancellationTokenSource` and it will dispose all its token's registrations.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass the cancellation token into `TrySetCanceled`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Yes. At the time I wrote this answer, that overload didn't exist. The [modern AsyncEx code](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/edb2c6b66d41471008a56e4098f9670b5143617e/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/CancellationTokenTaskSource.cs#L29) does pass the CT.

Comment: @StephenCleary, could you please mention and briefly describe your [`CancellationTokenTaskSource`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/CancellationTokenTaskSource.cs) in the answer so that people were better informed?

Answer (score 14):

```
Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken)
```

The answer you suggest in your question is the best solution to my knowledge. Here's why:

- It is safe
- Very small piece of code required
- Standard library

The `Task.Delay` approach is heavily used by a lot of folks as per my knowledge, and is also recommended on Microsoft blogs. [MSDN Example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/2017/11/18/implementing-background-tasks-in-microservices-with-ihostedservice-and-the-backgroundservice-class-net-core-2-x/).

Why write code (including tests) yourself leveraging `TaskCompletionSource` for converting a cancellation token to a task? It is preferable to leverage the standard libraries instead of reinventing the wheel; they are more likely to be bug free than your code.

Comment: Be warned that this call will always raise an `OperationCanceledException` when done, see docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay

Comment: Note that the timeout is `Timeout.Infinite`. Therefore, effectively, in practice, `OperationCanceledException` should never be called.

Comment: `OperationCanceledException` will be raised when the cancellationToken transition to canceled state

Comment: You are absolutely right. I somehow misread the `cancellationToken` as `CancellationToken.None`.

Comment: I don't think this is safe, it's safe only when the `cancellationToken` is canceled but what if it's never cancelled? you will have a never-end delay task. Each time using this will spawn such a never-end task. I think that would cause some issue if used too much.

Comment: If the cancellation token is never cancelled then the task is ongoing by definition. However, if you feel more comfortable, you can provide an upper limit in terms of time to  `Task.Delay` in addition to the cancellation token. I have tried other approaches of creating a task using cancellation token too but this approach is the easiest and least error-prone, and hence, I recommend it.