# Ensuring the Cancellation of some Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, cancellation

Suppose I want to ensure that a task object which is returned from an asynchronous method will transition into the canceled state, due to a cancellation request by the caller.

Catch is: this should occur regardless of how the asynchronous methods consumed by the aforementioned method are implemented and whether or not they ever complete.

Consider the following extension method:

```
    public static Task<T> ToTask<T>(this CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        cancellationToken.Register(() => { tcs.SetCanceled(); });
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

I can now consume such a task to ensure said scenario:

```
 public async Task<Item> ProvideItemAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task<Item> cancellationTask = cancellationToken.ToTask<Item>();

        Task<Item> itemTask = _itemProvider.ProvideItemAsync(cancellationToken);

        Task<Task<Item>> compoundTask = Task.WhenAny(cancellationTask, itemTask);

        Task<Item> finishedTask = await compoundTask;

        return await finishedTask;
    }
```

My questions are:

1) Are there any issues with this approach? 
2) Is there a built in API to facilitate such a use case

Thanks!

Comment: Is it `rawImageTask` or `itemTask`? `itemTask` is currently an unused local.

Comment: @spender Sorry, that one escaped editing.

Comment: "Regardless of how the actual operation is implemented" is not possible. Task cancellation is a cooperative process; if the task doesn't check anywhere if it's been cancelled, it won't actually get cancelled. Of course, you're still free to ignore the result in that case and *say* it was cancelled -- but it'll keep on running in the background.

Comment: @JeroenMostert. You are correct, but what I can ensure is that the client's request for cancellation is NOT utterly ignored, which is sometimes crucial. I have revised my question to further illustrate my intentions.

Comment: There's a problem with your `ToTask` method that's common to any approach that uses `Register`; this leaks resources. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670111/task-from-cancellation-token) for more information (and some proposed solutions). Including a link to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873173(v=vs.110).aspx#code-snippet-25), which seems to implement you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suppose I want to ensure the cancellation of an asynchronous operation,
>   Regardless of how the actual operation is implemented and whether or not it completes.

That is not possible unless you wrap the code into a separate process.

> When I say "ensure", I mean to say that the task denoting said operation transitions into the canceled state.

If you just want to cancel the *task* (and not the operation itself), then sure, you can do that.

> Are there any issues with this approach?

There's some tricky edge cases here. In particular, you need to dispose the result of `Register` if the task completes successfully.

I recommend using the [`WaitAsync` extension method](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/1.1.0/netstandard1.3/doc/Nito.AsyncEx.TaskExtensions/WaitAsync''1(System.Threading.Tasks.Task(''0),System.Threading.CancellationToken)) in my [`AsyncEx.Tasks` library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks):

```
public Task<Item> ProvideItemAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  return _itemProvider.ProvideItemAsync(cancellationToken).WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not take on dependencies at that Assembly level. I will, however, understand your implementation and use this knowledge to solve the issue at hand.

BTW, if I might say- Your work inspires a lot of ideas in my head. Thank you.

Comment: If I may ask, in your implementation of the DoWaitAsyncMethod- why did you invoke the 'ConfigureAwait' method with a false parameter? What does purpose does it serve?

Comment: @EyalPerry: I explain that in my [intro to `async` blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and my [`async` best practices article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: I have read both posts before, and I understand what ConfigureAwait(false) does, I will rephrase my question: by invoking ConfigureAwait(false), you cause the task instance to resume on a different synchronization context than the original one- which is not necessarily "expected" by the code consuming this extension method- I wholeheartedly agree that the practice you suggest is a good one, I just can't conceive a decision process which justifies doing this on a utility level such as the said extension method. I hope I did not "overstep", I mean all of this with great respect.

Comment: @EyalPerry: Each `await` captures its own context. So the decision is made locally: Does the `WaitAsync` method need to resume on a particular context? No, so use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Whether the *caller* needs to or not will be handled by the caller.

Comment: I understand that, but still - a decision to "switch contexts" has been made as a result of the call to this method.. would it not be best to leave such a decision up to the original caller, by providing him a means to control this behavior.. just for transparency's sake?

Comment: @EyalPerry: Perhaps I'm not explaining it right. The `ConfigureAwait(false)` inside `DoWaitAsyncMethod` has absolutely no effect on the context of any method that calls it. When the caller does its `await`, it is still on the same context.

Comment: What I understood is that eventually, there is some work, small as it may be,  that is offloaded to a different synchronization context. This is opaque to the caller, and therefore rings an alarm bell in my head. Thank you kindly for your patience.

Comment: false doesn't mean a different context. It means you don't care which context.

Comment: Then I guess I misunderstood what ConfigureAwait does. I will conduct further research. Thank you.