# Trying to learn cancellation tokens. Not sure why this does not work

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

So, I'm learning Cancellation tokens and I'm trying this example.  The `writeline` is never working even if I cancel this method from the outside.

So how this works, is the `initializeAsync`, if it takes too long, I have another method that cancels this task and then needs to alert the end user it was cancelled.  However, the `writeline` never happens when it is cancelled from an outside method.  `_cancelTask` is shared on the other method as well.

```cs
 internal static async Task<bool> SimConnectInitAsync()
  {
      _cancelTask = new CancellationTokenSource();

      await Task.Run(async ()=>
      {
          await InitializeAsync();
      }, _cancelTask.Token);

      Debug.WriteLine("Cancelled");
      _cancelTask.Cancel();
      _cancelTask.Dispose();

      return true;
  }
```

Never get `writeline` to trigger.  Cancels the entire method.

Comment: The `InitializeAsync` doesn't take a `CancellationToken` as argument. Do you want to cancel this method in a non-cooperative fashion? Short answer, [you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540260/stopping-a-task-without-a-cancellationtoken/77313824#77313824). Regarding the effect of the `CancellationToken` on the `Task.Run` method, see the "You keep using" meme in [this blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html "A Tour of Task, Part 9: Delegate Tasks") by Stephen Cleary.

Comment: Calling `_cancelTask.Cancel();` from outside will raise an exception in `SimConnectInitAsync` You are not handling that exception, thus, the `Debug.WriteLine` will never happen ...

Answer (score 0):

I think that your confusion is about the cancellation token that you pass in into the `Task.Run` method.

This token is only used if the task hasn't started yet. See the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-8.0#system-threading-tasks-task-run(system-func((system-threading-tasks-task))-system-threading-cancellationtoken)

> A cancellation token that can be used to cancel the work if it has not yet started.

This token can only be used in the few milliseconds between where you call the method `Task.Run` and that the inner task has found a thread to start it's work on. Once the inner task has started, then this cancellation token is no longer used.

Also, errors that are thrown inside of the method passed to `Task.Run` are thrown again when you await the result of `Task.Run`. This means that if you have an `OperationCancelledException` thrown inside the `InitializeAsync`, this will cause the `await Task.Run` to rethrow this exception, skipping the rest of this method.